# fancybox manual call to a specific target

Tags: jquery, function, hyperlink, fancybox, manual

I implemented the manual-script from fancybox:

```
$("#manual2").click(function() {
    $.fancybox([
        'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4044/4286199901_33844563eb.jpg',
        'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
        {
            'href'  : 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4213562882_851e92f326.jpg',
            'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
        }
    ], {
        'padding'           : 0,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'image',
        'changeFade'        : 0
    });
});
```

now I'm wondering, if it's possible to get directly to a specific picture by clicking on the link. (for example directly to the second other third picture).

Comment: ¿ (for example directly to the second other third picture).  ?

Comment: Wait a minute? I answered your first question, then your second question ... then JFK duplicates my answer to your second question and he gets the "best answer"? Please correct this.

Comment: @TimothyAaron: A moderator deleted my answer. I didn't mean any harm. It took me more than 5 minutes to write my answer and didn't see your comments in the meantime. I agree you should be awarded with the "correct answer" (I even voted up yours.) I apologize for any misunderstanding here.

Comment: Just for the record: I don't need to copy the (fancybox) code or answers of anybody else. I have actually answered more fancybox questions than anybody ever has (about 3,000) ... and actually most of my examples and code have been used (or copied) as reference in different forums (including stackoverflow) so please don't see me as an opportunist or like one who plagiarizes you. See http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/about for more. Sorry again for any inconvenience.

Comment: @JFK No problem. It's more an oversight of Marc's than yours; you were just trying to help. :)

Answer (score 3):

To start on the second slide just add `'index' : 1,` to your options json.

Here's it completely written out...

```
$("#manual2").click(function() {
    $.fancybox([
        'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4044/4286199901_33844563eb.jpg',
        'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
        {
            'href'  : 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4213562882_851e92f326.jpg',
            'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
        }
    ], {
        'index'             : 1,
        'padding'           : 0,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'image',
        'changeFade'        : 0
    });
});
```

Must have version 1.3.1 or higher.
See the Fancybox API for more details: http://fancybox.net/api

**UPDATE:**
You asked if the index can be set from the links themselves, and the answer is yes. Just make sure you set which slide you want to open using a custom `data-` attribute (e.g., `data-index="2"`), then use this instead of the previous code ...

```
$("#manual2").click(function() {
    $.fancybox([
        'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4044/4286199901_33844563eb.jpg',
        'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
        {
            'href'  : 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4213562882_851e92f326.jpg',
            'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
        }
    ], {
        'index'             : $(this).data('index'),
        'padding'           : 0,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'image',
        'changeFade'        : 0
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't forget computer arrays start at 0, so you'll have to subtract a 1 from whichever slide you want to start at.

Comment: is ist possible to set the index within the link-tag? something like:

[code]<a href="javasript: function( 2 );" id="#manual2">click</a>[/code]

and 

[code]$("#manual2").click(function( pic_index ) {
...
'index' : pic_index,
...[/code]

Comment: Sure can. In your fancybox options use `'index':$(this).data('index')` then just add a `data-index="2"`attribute to your link.

_ps. in comments, use the ` character instead of [code]_

Comment: +1 to Timothy: index is the right option ... but then you are asking a second question. See my answer.

Comment: @Marc-AlexanderIten: Could you please reconsider the correct answer?  I think Timothy here has helped you the most.  Timothy, you might want to [edit] to update your answer with your comments.  Comments are liable to disappear at any moment...

Comment: I would just add that if Marc wants to have a valid code, then he should use `<!DOCTYPE html>` since `data-` attributes are valid for `HTML5` only.