# fancybox manual call adds previous values

Tags: jquery, function, fancybox, gallery, manual

I just asked several days ago about [fancybox manual call to a specific target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116403/fancybox-manual-call-to-a-specific-target)

now I have a further problem. I like to implement more than one fancybox gallery. The first gallery works well. But when I include a second one (e.g. code:)

```
    $("#manual1").click(function() {
        $.fancybox([
            'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4044/4286199901_33844563eb.jpg',
            'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
            {
                'href'  : 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4213562882_851e92f326.jpg',
                'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
            }
        ], {...
        });
    });
$("#manual2").click(function() {
        $.fancybox([
            'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4044/4286199901_33844563eb.jpg',
            'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
            {
                'href'  : 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4213562882_851e92f326.jpg',
                'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
            }
        ], {...
        });
    });
```

the second gallery includes the pictures from the first. So in this example I will have a first gallery (#manual1) with 3 pictures and a second gallery (#manual2) with 6 pictures. But I like to have only 3 pics in the second one. (And a third one is even worse).

How can I solve this problem? `$.fancybox().removeData();` doesn't work as well as `$('something_in_here').fancybox(` does not help.

Comment: sorry guys, it was a php-problem... (sometimes I have tomatoes on my eyes)
thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy the same code and only change the selector, of course you will have the same information.

Here is where you define what pictures for each gallery

```
$.fancybox([
            'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4044/4286199901_33844563eb.jpg',
            'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
            {
                'href'  : 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4213562882_851e92f326.jpg',
                'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
            }
        ],
```

so change the path accordingly for each gallery

```
http://newSite.com/newPath/newImage.jpg
```

Comment: you missunderstood me. the problem is not, that there are the same pictures (of course, I know, but the example above is from the fancybox-website, in my case I have different pictures in it). the problem is, that a second gallery starts with the pictures of the first one and then those of the second one.
you can do an easy testpage to see what I mean. take the example from the fancybox website and include it two times at the same page. then you will see the difference...

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but the scope isn't defined...what if you tried something like     `$(this).fancybox([`

Comment: no, sorry... then I will get the output "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."